# Android: I have an array of HashMaps, how to find a particular HashMap entry given a key that is within one of the HashMap entries?

Tags: android

I have an array of HashMaps, how to find a particular HashMap entry given a key that is within one of the HashMap entries?

For example, I have this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bathroomList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I also know a key within one of the array entries I want to find:

```
String selectedKey = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.key)).getText().toString();
```

How do I iterate the array to find it?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A map is a dictionary. For each key, it has one and only one entry. And there's no point in iterating over a map to find a key, since the whole point af a map is to be able to get the entry for a key in a single method call (O(1) for a HashMap):

```
String value = map.get(selectedKey)
```

will get you the value associated with `selectedKey` in the map.

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask this is how can I iterate this data structure looking for a particular value? Noting, it is an array of HashMaps. ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bathroomList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: Well, iterate over the maps, and for each map, iterate over its values (Map has a `values()` method). But if you're looking for values and not for keys, then you have a design problem. The values should be the keys. Also, if you have the value, what's the point in finding it in the map: you already have it?

Comment: Trying to match the selectedKey with the key in the data structure so I can access the full record. Could you provide an example of your suggestion?

Comment: Frankly, you're not clear at all. I selectedKey a key of your map, or a value of your map? If it's a key, map.get(selectedKey) returns the associated value. If it's a value, I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: SelectedKey is a the selected key in a listView. Once I have that key, I just need to find the corresponding data record.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like a regular for loop to iterate over the arraylist and then just check for null You cannot iterate over a hashmap but if you look for a key and it is not there then it will just return null.

```
ArrayList< HashMap< String, Object>> bathroomList; //this must be initialized.
public String getEntry(String key) {
    int count = bathroomList.length(); // this might be size i can never
                                        // remember
    String result = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result = ((String) bathroomList[i].get(key));
        if (result != null) {
            break;
        }
    }
            if(result == null){
            result = "Key Not Found";
            }
     return result;   
}
```

Edit to map hashmaps.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getData(String key) {
    String[] hashmapKeys = {"key1", "key2", "key3"};
    if(key.equals("key1"){
        return bathroomList[0];
    }
        if(key.equals("key2"){
        return bathroomList[1];
    }
        if(key.equals("key3"){
        return bathroomList[2];
    }

}
```

Might i suggest using a different data structure. If you already know that you are maping things with keys then instead of an `ArrayList< HashMap< String, String > >` you could use a `HashMap< String, HashMap<String, String>>`

`HashMap< String, HashMap<String, String>> bathroomList;`

then to get your dataset use

`HashMap<String, String>> dataSelected =`bathroomList.get(selectedKey);`

Most of the time when you pick something out of a list you will use the arraylist because you pass in the position of the list that the user clicked on. The position in the list is what determines what data was selected anyways.

Comment: I am not working with strings this is the data structure.
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bathroomList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: you are clearly working with strings. Each entry in your hashmap is a string and you have a string for your key.  The for loop iterates over the arraylist so each hashmap will be checked for your specific key.

Comment: Ahh you are trying to have your entries in the arraylist be named by a key. That is not possible. You can map them out. by using a String array.